# What is the WPF version of Control.MouseButtons?

Tags: wpf

What is the WPF version of Control.MouseButtons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MouseButtonState

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttonstate.aspx

Comment: MouseButtonState is the equiv to Forms.MouseButtons.. but the question was in regards to Control.MouseButtons.  See my answer below for the correct equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

NVM's answer is wrong.

[Control.MouseButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousebuttons.aspx) is a static property that tells which mouse buttons are currently down.

[Input.MouseButtonState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttonstate.aspx) is merely an enum.

---

**The correct answer is [Input.Mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.aspx).**  This is a static class that has an individual property per button so that you can check if that specific button is pressed or not.